# Java Multi-threading How to Calculate and Limit the Maximum Number of Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

Context to the question;

This is a single bit of code that is triggered by pressing 'go'. Within the code, it branches out multiple threads because the activity per action (i.e. doSomething() within a for-each loop) is really slow, yet very low on processor/memory/hard drive space requirements.

As such, I tried branching out every single iteration of the loop to create a new thread and well.... things just absolutely melted ha ha. Out of Memory exceptions being thrown everywhere.

I want to run this multi-threaded, but how do I go about limiting the available threads within the code base to an acceptable level so that the application continues to work without melting?

I've not had to deal a lot with single source multi-threading previously (web applications are naturally multi-threaded, but also mutli-source and hence easier to manage supply/demand on the server resources).

The application in question doesn't actually need to run this piece of functionality multi-threaded, it would just be better if it did. In reality it doesn't make much difference if the code takes 1 hr to complete or 100 hrs, but for my own sanity, I'd like to to be as efficient as possible.

Pointers?

Comment: Too little information on your actual problem.  Needs code at least.  Whole books have been written on the subject of how one should design multi-threaded code, I doubt we could provide a reasonable general answer.

Comment: [Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) seems like a good start.